# How to access values from a nest in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
name,score,date
Bob,93,2014
Bob,85,2015
Barry,70,2015
```

No two people have the same name, but a person can have multiple entries. I've created a [nest](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#-nest) with this code:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(data){
  data = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d){ return d.name })
      .entries(data);
```

The nest looks like this:

```
[{key: "Bob", values: [
   {score: 93, date: 2014},
   {score: 85, date: 2015}]},
 {key: "Barry", values: [
   {score: 70, date: 2015}]}]
```

How can I get the max of all the scores using d3.max?

**Edit:**

When testing solutions I was using different data than in my question. I was getting a result but it wasn't the max. This was because I wasn't explicitly converting my score value to a number with the `+` operator.

D3_GXT_Java's answer lead me to realize that I was using the right strategy but something small was off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get minimum and maximum values by passing your nested data and returning the object for which you want minimum and maximum values. Look at [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/y4R3331Wy0d9d4opu8PZ?p=info).

```
 x.domain([d3.min(updated, function(d) {
      return d3.min(d.values, function(d) {
        return (d.score);
      });
    }),
    d3.max(updated, function(d) {
      return d3.max(d.values, function(d) {
        return (d.score);
      });
    })
  ]);

  y.domain([d3.min(updated, function(d) {
    return d3.min(d.values, function(d) {
      return  parseInt(d.date);
    });
  }), d3.max(updated, function(d) {
    return d3.max(d.values, function(d) {
      return parseInt(d.date);
    });
  })]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well `D3.max()` takes an array, so you first need to flatten the items into an array before processing. This can be done using a `map` then `reduce` function on the array:

```js
var data = [{
  key: "Bob",
  values: [{
    score: 93,
    date: 2014
  }, {
    score: 85,
    date: 2015
  }]
}, {
  key: "Barry",
  values: [{
    score: 70,
    date: 2015
  }]
}];

var items = data.map(function(d) { return d.values; })
                .reduce(function(a, b) { return a.concat(b); });

console.log(items);

var max = d3.max(items, function(d) { return d.score; });
console.log(max);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @user2829582 I fail still to see why this answer doesn't do what you want? I've compared it to the answer you accepted and if you change the `data` variable for `updated` then this works absolutely fine. I've even tried it in the plunker from the accepted answer...

Comment: @user2829582: Accepting an answer should provide you with enough reputation to start voting.

Comment: I updated my question with details about my accepted answer. Your answer will be voted up when I reach 15 rep. I'm at 10 rep now.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_max), d3.max takes a second parameter that is a function that returns the value you want to use in the max calculation. You can rest two of these functions together to get the result you're looking for.

```
var i = [{key: "Bob", values: [
   {score: 93, date: 2014},
   {score: 85, date: 2015}]},
 {key: "Barry", values: [
   {score: 70, date: 2015}]}];


var max = d3.max(i, function(row) {
   return d3.max(row.values, function(value) {
      return value.score;
   });
});

console.log(max)
```